# Update table based on range of values from another table in r

Tags: r

I'd like to update a table (`lws_data`) based on information from another table (`df_unique`). The `head()` for both tables are given below. As not all values of `df_unique$org_rowid` are present in `lws_data` the update should be based on a close match (similar to Vlookup True (approx.match)). The expected output is shown in the snip below (`exp_out`). I tried using join but the output was not matching with what I expected. Appreciate all your inputs.

- Table lws_data

  dput(head(lws_data_1,30))
  structure(list(V1 = 1:30), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("data.table",
  "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001f900011ef0>)
- Table df_unique

  dput(head(df_unique,30))
  structure(list(org_rowid = c(1L, 302L, 537L, 749L, 1082L, 1266L,
  1728L, 2177L, 2362L, 2998L, 3049L, 3361L, 3366L, 3427L, 3748L,
  3781L, 3805L, 4053L, 4667L, 4772L, 4776L, 4807L, 4909L, 5017L,
  5544L, 5653L, 5660L, 5666L, 5676L, 5700L), event_definition_2 = c(0,
  1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10,
  11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8VUJ.jpg]

Comment: Please include a `dput(head(df, 30))` for all dfs involved, or dummy data if it is confidential, as well as code to help us reproduce your issue.

Comment: @dcsuka - Thanks edited to have dput data now

Comment: We cannot reproduce this, as there is a pointer in the data. Please ensure that you can run your sample data in a fresh R session.

Comment: The existence of a pointer means tha tyou were using data.table objects and not telling us. The pointer is not going to be useful to us since we are not using the same setup as you. You should edit you question to a) load the data.table package and then b) build objects and then show you code for the join and then c) explicitly say what you were expecting.